# Google play removed my app from store because of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

Google play store removed my app from store because of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission.

They want from me to describe the sepecific package visibilities required in my application. But I don't know how to describe it.

I wrote my app Flutter 2.10.0

Can someone help me for this issue?

My pubspec.yaml

```
name: xxxxx
description: A new Flutter project. 
version: 3.0.6+14

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
 
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  intl: ^0.17.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  indexed: ^0.0.6
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  flutter_html: ^2.2.1
  webview_flutter: ^2.8.0
  fl_chart: ^0.41.0
  vexana: ^2.8.0
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.3
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+4
  path_provider: ^2.0.8
  jwt_decoder: ^2.0.1
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.3.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.2
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.0
  internet_connection_checker: ^0.0.1+2
  connectivity_plus: ^1.0.8
  reorderable_grid_view: ^2.2.2
  photo_view: ^0.13.0
  file_picker: ^4.3.2  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter 
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.3


flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/app_icon/app_icon.png"
    
flutter:

  
  uses-material-design: true

   assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/logos/
    - assets/images/categories/
    - assets/images/social_icons/ 
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

 
fonts :
    - family : Poppins Bold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset : assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset : assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
        - asset : assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset : assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
```

My android manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.kolayilanmobile">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<queries> 
    <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app makes calls -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent> 
</queries>
<application android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:label="Kolay İlan" android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
        <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
             Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
             screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
             gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
             Flutter's first frame. -->
        <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value=""/>
</application>
```